# Convert Query into Fetch-XMLQury

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I want to change select query into FetchXML Query. 
My query is

```sql
SELECT * FROM new_periodtotal    
JOIN product ON product.pruductid = new_periodtotal.product
JOIN new_program ON new_program.product = new_periodtotal.product
```

Problem is there is no direct relationship with new_periodtotal and new_periodtotal
both have relationship with Product.
how I convert it in fetchXML query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a structure like that at hand to test this out, but I'll try to extrapolate a solution based on the OP query. Some additional tuning / trial&error might be required.

If `product.productid = new_periodtotal.product` and `new_program.product = new_periodtotal.product` then `product.productid = new_program.product`.

You in fact have a realtionship, though it's "indirect": both entities would have non-empty "product" fields.

To obtain the FetchXML I would build an Advanced Find like this:

Search entity: `product`

- (Related) new_periodtotal

  - (product field) -> contains data
  - (related) new_program

    - (product field) -> contains data

The third row is meant to look in the related of the related, hence the increased indentation.

It would read like this: "get all product records where the related new_periodtotal records have a non-empty product field, and where the related new_program records of the related new_periodtotal records have  non-empty product field".

After that, you can `Download FetchXML` (up in the ribbon) to get the query.